# Python fsolve shape of fprime is wrong?

Tags: python, scipy

The following could not be much simpler, yet I cannot find how to make it work...

```
from scipy.optimize import fsolve

def a(x):
    return x*x-x

def ap(x):
    return 2*x-1

#works
print(fsolve(a, 0.3))

#works
print(fsolve(a, 0.3, fprime=ap))

#works
print(fsolve(a, [0.3], fprime=ap))

#works
print(fsolve(a, [0.3, 0.7]))

#crashes
print(fsolve(a, [0.3, 0.7], fprime=ap))
```

When it crashes is gives the error

```
TypeError: fsolve: there is a mismatch between the input and output shape of the 'fprime' argument 'ap'.Shape should be (2, 2) but it is (2,).
```

The output dimension of `ap` seems like it should definitely be the same as the input. How could this possibly be going wrong (and how do I fix it)?

I think some downvoters are missing the subtlety of the question so here is a more in depth explanation of why I am confused:

It seems that scipy interprets `a` as a function of one variable with `[0.3,0.7]` starting estimates of two roots in `fsolve(a, [0.3, 0.7])`, but in `fsolve(a, [0.3, 0.7], fprime=ap)` it interprets `a` as function of two variables with `[.3,.7]` being the estimate of a single root. According to the documentation (https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.optimize.fsolve.html), the second argument

```
x0 : ndarray
    The starting estimate for the roots of func(x) = 0.
```

says that it is looking for estimate of the roots (**plural**). But its behavior in the case where `fprime` is given makes it sound like `x0` is interpreted as an estimate of a single root.

Comment: What output do you think you're going to get in the following code: `ap([0.3, 0.7])`

Comment: scipy is asking for a 2x2 output from ap(x), because that's the form of the [jacobian matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jacobian_matrix_and_determinant).

Comment: @eyllanesc I would not expect scipy to pass in a list, but instead an array, and I would expect `ap(np.array([0.3, 0.7])) == np.array([ap(0.3), ap(0.7)])` which is indeed true. If you want to allow `ap` to take in lists, I would instead define it as `return 2*np.array(x)-1`, but this does not solve the shape mismatch issue.

Comment: Could some downvoters explain why this is a bad question? To me it seems nontrivial why the second to last one `fsolve(a, [0.3, 0.7])` works but `fsolve(a, [0.3, 0.7], fprime=ap)` doesn't.

Comment: Also @sascha I realize the jacobian of a function of two variables is a 2x2 matrix, but the jacobian of a function of one variable is also a function of one variable, so my question is why does scipy interpret `a` as a function of one variable with `[.3,.7]` starting estimates of two roots in `fsolve(a, [0.3, 0.7])`, but in `fsolve(a, [0.3, 0.7], fprime=ap)` it interprets `a` as function of two variables with `[.3,.7]` being the estimate of a single root?

Comment: **It does not**. When not giving fprime, it just uses numerical-diff automatically. And you see that the output is a vector corresponding to a function with two variables. (**edit:** Warren also explained it; did not see it!)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks to everyone who explained why I was getting the behavior I was getting. No one actually told me how to fix the issue though, so I'm writing this answer since I figured it out.

The confusion stems from the fact that the scipy documentation is somewhere between wrong and misleading.

The documentation says:

> Return the roots of the (non-linear) equations defined by func(x) = 0 given a starting estimate.

suggesting that for a scalar function it may return an array of roots. The actual behavior is closer to

> Returns a root of the (non-linear) equation defined by func(x) = 0 given a starting estimate.

This would have made what to do obvious. To find multiple roots of the equation, we can let scipy (as it always does) interpret `a(x)` as a function of `n` variables, where `n` is the length of `x`. To find multiple roots let `a` be vectorized, i.e.

`a([x1, x2, ..., xn]) = [a(x1), a(x2), ..., a(xn)]`.

The jacobian of this function is a diagonal matrix

`diag([ap(x1), ap(x2), ..., ap(xn)])`.

Thus **the answer to my question is**:

Change

```
print(fsolve(a, [0.3, 0.7], fprime=ap))
```

to

```
print(fsolve(a, [0.3, 0.7], fprime=lambda x: np.diag(ap(x))))
# correctly outputs
# [ -3.69321143e-16   1.00000000e+00]
```

or simply loop over `[0.3, 0.7]` calling `fsolve` once per initial guess.

Answer (score 2):

I suspect you expected `fsolve(a, [0.3, 0.7], fprime=ap)` to return two solutions to the scalar problem.  `fsolve` does not work that way.

When you call `fsolve(a, x0, fprime=ap)`, the `fsolve` function infers the dimensions of the problem from the shape of `x0`.  If `x0` is a scalar, it expects `a` to accept a scalar, and `fprime` must accept a scalar and return a scalar (or a 1x1 array).  If `x0` is a sequence of length 2 (as in your example that didn't work), `fsolve` expects `a` to accept an array of length 2 as its `x` argument and return a sequence of length 2.  It also expects `fprime` to accept a array of length 2 and return an array (the Jacobian matrix) with shape 2x2.

Comment: Indeed, the documentation for scipy.optimize.fsolve says that the second argument `x0` is `The starting estimate for the roots of func(x) = 0.` To me this sounds like it wants estimates for all of the roots. Indeed, `fsolve(a, np.array([0.3, 0.7]))` returns `[ -2.76444148e-16   1.00000000e+00]
` so that seems to be correct. Why does the behavior change when I give it fprime?

Comment: If you call `a(np.array([0.3, 0.7]))`, the function returns `array([-0.21, -0.21])`, so it is a perfectly well-behaved function of two values that returns two values.  The Jacobian of such a function is a 2-D matrix with shape 2x2 (or, in numpy terms, a 2-D array with shape (2, 2)).  That is the matrix that must be returned by `ap` for it to be consistent with `fsolve`.   With your function, `ap(np.array([0.3, 0.7])` returns `array([-0.4,  0.4])`.  That is the wrong shape for the Jacobian of `a(x)`.  (If you don't use the argument `fprime`, `fsolve` computes the Jacobian numerically.)